# Чтение файлов в структуру(сериализация)

Tags: c, файлы, структуры, сериализация, struct

Я новичок в программировании. Сейчас разбираюсь со струкрурами. У меня такая задача - наполнить свою структуру(ManCity) данными из файла(название файла перепроверил, все ок). Вроде как делаю все правильно, но почему то выводит такую штуку(внизу все есть), а если конкретно то у меня вопрос почему выводит:

- Первые две структуры (Alex Zinchenko и Serhio Aguero);
- Вторую структуру выводит 2 раза(и оба раза неправильно);
- Почему выводимые структуры не подставляются под мою форму (в самом
  низу перед return я написал printf, и надеялся что все данные
  подставятся под этот текст);

Зарание все спасибо!

Содержимое файла:

```
Alex Zinchenko 22 G Ukraine
Serhio Aguero 27 G Agrentina
Benjamen Mendy 28 B France
Riad Mahrez 25 B Algeria
David Silva 28 G Spain
```

Код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct teams {
    char name[15];
    char surname[15];
    int age;
    char pos;
    char country[15];
};

int main() {
    struct teams ManCity;
    FILE* fp = fopen("mancity.txt", "r");
    fread(&ManCity, sizeof(struct teams), 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    printf("%s %s is %d years old, play as %c from %s\n", ManCity.name, ManCity.surname, ManCity.age, ManCity.pos, ManCity.country);
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
Alex Zinchenko 22 G Ukraine
Serhio Aguero 27 G Agre� 22 G Ukraine
Serhio Aguero 27 G Agre� is 544172392 years old, play as A from guero 27 G Agre�
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша ошибка в том, что вы читаете из текстового файла данные, как из бинарного. Увы, это не проходит.

Читать нужно примерно так -

```
fscanf(fp,"%s %s %d %c %s",ManCity.name,ManCity.surname,&ManCity.age,&ManCity.pos,ManCity.country);
```

Словом, [чтение из текстового файла](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Чтобы читать так, как читает вы - данные должны быть точно так же и записаны в файл, с помощью `fwrite`, и файл должен быть открыт как бинарный, а не текстовый...